# Split without Removing Delimeter using Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

> OWENS CROSS ROA 530 LYONS ROAD

I need to split the above line into the following:

```
OWENS CROSS ROA

530 LYONS ROAD
```

The delimiter is numbers i.e. 530.

I need to read up to 530, then split as:

> OWENS CROSS ROA 
> 530 LYONS ROAD

My attempt:

```
address.text.split(/([0-9]+)/)
```

Output:

```
OWENS CROSS ROA 
530
```

LYONS ROAD is not picked up.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a pattern like this:

```
/\s+(?=\d)/
```

The `(?=…)` here is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors). This will match any sequence of one or more whitespace characters which is followed by a digit character, but thanks to the assertion, the digit will not be part of the matched string.

For example:

```
"OWENS CROSS ROA 530 LYONS ROAD".split(/\s+(?=\d)/)
=> ["OWENS CROSS ROA", "530 LYONS ROAD"]
```

Comment: Worked successfully. Can you please explain the regex?

Comment: @user311509 it is called positive lookbehind you can check the documentation at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html

Comment: @bjhaid Actually, that's a lookahead. `(?<=…)` is a lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a solution using only one basic Regular Expression and string indices:

```
address_str = 'OWENS CROSS ROA 530 LYONS ROAD'

# String index of digits in address_str
number_location = address_str.index(/\d+/)

address = []
address << address_str[0, number_location]    
address << address_str[number_location, address_str.length]
```

`/\d+/` just means "Match one or more digits."

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good candidate for using `scan`. Instead I'd use a very simple pattern to capture the parts you want:

```
pt1, pt2 = /^(.+?) (\d+.+)/.match('OWENS CROSS ROA 530 LYONS ROAD').captures
puts pt1, pt2
# >> OWENS CROSS ROA
# >> 530 LYONS ROAD
```

Rubular can help you [decipher it](http://rubular.com/r/0Jiyb2spt5).

You *can* do it with `scan` if you insist:

```
'OWENS CROSS ROA 530 LYONS ROAD'.scan(/^(.+?) (\d+.+)/)
# => [["OWENS CROSS ROA", "530 LYONS ROAD"]]
```

but you'll be adding complexity, either to undo the nested sub-array, or in the pattern to avoid using the captures.